# How to write routing if already used any keyboard

Tags: codeigniter, routes

Hi i used the routing for search like

```
  $route['test-degrees/(:any)/(:num)/(:any)']='test/all_degrees/$1/$2/$3';
```

and i need to add new degree like

```
$route['test-degrees/(:any)/(:num)/(:add-degree-record)']="test-degrees/(:any)/(:num)/adddegreerecord";
```

but its does not call the adddegreerecord method. call the all_degree method

Comment: From the [docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#wildcards): Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

Comment: Also `:add-degree-record` isn't a valid wildcard type. I think your route should be like this `$route['test-degrees/(:any)/(:num)/add-degree-record']="<your_controller>/<your_method>/$1/$2"` and be declared before the first routing.